# Widget LockScreen issue

Tags: android, widget, keyguard

I create a keyguard widget that has a button that upsate textview with Random number when clicking. it works properly on the home screen but on the lock screen (android 4.2.2) it(s button) works just when i add it to my lock screen widgets but when i turn screen off and return; it(s button) doesn't work !!

**Widget.java**

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 50000);
    }

    class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;
        Context context;

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetReceive.class);
        configIntent.setAction("updateTextView");
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, configPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(100)));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    }


}
```

**WidgetReceive.java**

```
public class WidgetReceive extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

        if(intent.getAction().equals("updateTextView")){
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(100)));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/> 
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>   
    <receiver android:name=".WidgetReceive">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="updateTextView"/> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that the following line

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, configPendingIntent);
```

is missing from `WidgetReceive.onReceive(...)`

When updating an app widget with a `RemoteViews` object, you must create all the contents of the widget, including the listeners, every time.